# Can't find link to add content to pages

Tags: sidebar, links, dashboard, duplicates

I'm new to wordpress and I'm facing a problem.

On one site I'm using wordpress v3.5.1 and I am using links in the sidebar to add content and images to several pages:

[image: Left sidebar with links]
As you can see on the left I have: Dagaanbieding, Winkels, Outlets, Assortiment.

This site was made by another guy, so I don't know how it's made exactly.

Now I've installed a new wordpress (3.8.1) and Copied the files over because the website has to be the same. I've already exported and imported the contents and pages from the other website, but there are no links (Dagaanbieding, Winkels, Outlets, Assortiment) in the left sidebar. How do I create them?

[image: left sidebar with links 2]

Hopefully it's not a big problem.

EDIT:

First website (wordpress 3.5.1)

Activated:

> - Advanced custom fields
> - Contact form 7
> - Cookie control
> - Dashboard widget sidebar
> - Easy WordPress Mailchimp Integration
> - Social media widget
> - Super RSS reader
> - Types - Complete Solution for Custom Fields and Types
> - Twitter Widget

Deactivated:

> - Child Pages Shortcode
> - Featured Post

Second website (wordpress 3.8.1)

Activated:

> - Advanced Custom Fields
> - Social Media Widget
> - Super RSS Reader
> - WordPress Importer

Deactivated:

> - Hallo Dolly
> - Child Pages Shortcode
> - Attachment Files Importer
> - Akismet

NOTE: I had Dashboard widget sidebar installed, but then I got an error with some kind of foreach loop in the plugin. When I disabled it, the error was gone.

Comment: Can we see a list of activated and deactivated plugins? I'm also assuming you're using Dutch translations correct?

Comment: Will edit my post to add activated and deactivated plugins, also it's dutch yes.

Comment: @TomJNowell edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Custom Post Types are probably set up with the Plugin "Types - Complete Solution for Custom Fields and Types" that is missing on the second install.

According to their docs this plugin has an export/import feature. You can use it to export in the old install and then import the Custom Post Types in the new install.

Comment: I've edited my post with the installed plugins in both sites.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help :) This was indeed the problem.